# How to have an element change its color during a scroll event and then revert back to its original color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am trying to make the footer of a website im creating change color DURING scrolling and revert back to its original color after the scroll is done.
Is there any way to detect when a scroll event ends?

I am looking for answers in vanilla js. Or if there are any specific recoomendation available in for example jQuery im more than willing to look into it per your kind suggestion.

Comment: You can add an onscroll event to your code. If the onscroll event goes on then it should change the color as you wish

Comment: what do you mean with when the scroll is done?

Answer (score 0):

So you're probably looking for scroll event handeler [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll#:%7E:text=document.getElementById(%27log%27)%3B-,textarea.onscroll,-%3D%20logScroll%3B%0A%0Afunction%20logScroll)

And to check if you're done scrolling to the bottom, you need to check if the scroll height is left or not? [This](https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll-window) might help with that!

Answer (score 0):

Using code I got from [detecting when a visitor has stopped scrolling](https://gomakethings.com/detecting-when-a-visitor-has-stopped-scrolling-with-vanilla-javascript/) I derived this:

```js
// Setup isScrolling variable
var isScrolling;

// Listen for scroll events
window.addEventListener('scroll', function ( event ) {

    // Clear our timeout throughout the scroll
    window.clearTimeout( isScrolling );

    // Set a timeout to run after scrolling ends
    isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {

        // Run the callback
  if(document.querySelector('#mydiv').style.background=='red')
      document.querySelector('#mydiv').style.background='blue';
  else if(document.querySelector('#mydiv').style.background=='blue')
    document.querySelector('#mydiv').style.background='yellow'
  else 
    document.querySelector('#mydiv').style.background='red'

    }, 66);

}, false);
```

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  height:400vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>scroll down this(document should change colour when you stop:</h1>
  <div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
```

You just set a timeout to wait until the user is done scrolling. If the user continues to scroll the timeout is cleared and reset before it activates(meaning the code won't run until he stops).

Comment: As soon as the scroll activates you can have the color change, just make sure the revert is in the timeout .

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ***window height*** and the ***height of your footer*** element and check the scroll `pageYOffset` in relation to the *window height* => `window.innerHeight` and the footers `top` position in relation to the viewport => `footer.getBoundingClientRect().top`.

Use a set of conditionals to check the scroll position. Set it anywhere you'd like for the initial color change, I used the initial `window.innerHeight` to start the BG color change.

For the bg-color change, I use a *class* and add it to the body with `classList.add('bgColor')`. Then we further check if the ***pageYOffset*** is greater than the `window.innerHeight - footer.getBoundingClientRect().top`, meaning the footer will just be breaking the bottom fold of the page and coming into view, if this happens we remove the class that adds the bg-color and return the document to its initial bg-color.

```js
const height = 3000;
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--height", `${height}px`)

const display = document.getElementById('display')

const footer = document.querySelector('.footer')
const rect = footer.getBoundingClientRect()
const screenHeight = window.innerHeight

function setBgOnScroll(e) {
  let offset = window.pageYOffset
  display.textContent = `scroll offset: ${offset} footer top position: ${rect.top - screenHeight}`
  offset > screenHeight ?
    document.body.classList.add('bgColor') : document.body.classList.remove('bgColor')
  offset > rect.top - screenHeight ?
    document.body.classList.remove('bgColor') : null
}

window.addEventListener('scroll',setBgOnScroll)
```

```css
:root {
  --body-bg-color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--body-bg-color);
  transition: background-color ease-in-out 500ms;
}

.cont {
  height: var(--height);
}

#display {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 220px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(3000px - 100px);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bgColor {
  background-color: lightblue;
  transition: background-color ease-in-out 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div id="display"></div>
  Page content, scroll down...
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can react to the scroll event with Javascript you'll need to define some timings to decide when the user has stopped scrolling.

As you can't sense a 'not-scrolling' event this will have to be with something like a setTimeout.

```html
<style>
div {
  height: 300vh;
}
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: magenta;
}
</style>
<body>
<div>scroll down</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
<script>
let timeout = false;
const footer = document.querySelector('footer');
document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  if (timeout) {clearTimeout(timeout); timeout = false;}
  footer.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  timeout = setTimeout( function () {
    footer.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }, 1000);
});
</script>
</body>
```